# How PID (Process Indentifier) is generated in kernel-mode under Windows?

Tags: kernel, pid

I would like to know how Process Identifier(s) (aka PID)s are generated under Windows. Is it unique across different machines? e.g., consider the 5856 id that's currently assigned to my Firefox program. Is it same for the same executable image under another machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process identifiers are not unique across different machines. They can be reused on the same machine for later processes and will typically not be the same between two invocations of the same executable.

You are not supposed to care about how it is being generated - the only thing that you can be sure of is that the process identifier uniquely identifies a single running process, i.e. there will only be one process having that identifier at any one time.

Comment: Well, do you know on what basis it's generated?

Comment: No, that is not documented and may change between Windows versions or service packs or updates or depending on the time of day or the phase of the moon. :)

Comment: It was so informative, specially the "phase of the moon" section :)

Comment: Your welcome! :) Ok, more seriously, I'm just trying to point out that you simply cannot rely on any specific behavior. You could try posting another question that says what you are trying to accomplish - there might be some help to get there instead.

Answer (score 6):

A PIDs generation is mostly a secret that Microsoft won't officially document - because they would have to stick to that implementation once they've documented it. However, it is always a multiple of 4 - but this isn't a behavior you should rely on. They aren't unique, and they can be re-used.

Raymond Chen mentions this in his [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/28/7925962.aspx).

Comment: They are only a multiple of 4 due to a side-effect; this is not by design and could, theoretically, change.

Comment: Yes - that's precisely what Raymond points out in his blog. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Process, thread, and kernel handle IDs come from a common routine.  Technically this is a DWORD though I don't remember the last time I saw them above 65,536.  They can be reused, and it's just a counter-based mechanism.

Comment: I *have* seen such processes once on Windows 10, with some 6-digit PIDs. But that's a rarity.

Answer (score 2):

Processes are maintained as objects in the kernel and, as such, are exported to user mode the same way as every other object in the system (i.e. events, mutexes, semaphores, timers, etc) via HANDLEs.

Thus, the process IDs are really just HANDLEs to process objects, which are maintained in a global handle table (the PspCidTable, as an implementation detail). As an interesting aside, threads are also maintained as objects and are also inserted into this table. The thread IDs then are really just HANDLEs to thread objects.

-scott